# VSCodium update: The certificate is NOT trusted

Tags: apt, updates

Trying to `apt update` gives this error for VSCodium:

```
Err:7 https://download.vscodium.com/debs vscodium InRelease                                                                                    
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 138.199.36.10 443]
```

```
W: Failed to fetch https://download.vscodium.com/debs/dists/vscodium/InRelease  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 138.199.36.10 443]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What could I do to fix this problem?

Ubuntu 22.04.3, fully updated

Comment: @guiverc updated the question. Certificates should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your CA certificates and everything to do with how SSL certificates are validated.

When you go to the site `download.vscodium.com`, that URL has **invalid SSL certificates** being served.  While the site is `download.vscodium.com`, the SSL certificate that is presented is only valid for `*.b-cdn.net`. This is why SSL validation fails, and is a huge red flag about the trustworthiness of the site.

From a security standpoint, this needs to be fixed by the remote administrators who maintain that domain, and it is strongly recommended by best security practices that you **do not trust this source for repositories** until this is fixed by those administrators.  Unfortunately, this can only be fixed by the VSCodium site maintainers properly presenting valid SSL and redirects to proper `b-cdn.net` endpoints that will properly validate.

---

However, **if you insist on using this improperly configured repository URL** despite my suggestion to not trust the site or domain until they fix their stuff, then you need to do the following:

1. Create the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80-ssl-exceptions` by running `sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80-ssl-exceptions`.
2. Put the following into that file (edit it as superuser with a sudo command and your favorite command line editor):

   ```
   Acquire::https::download.vscodium.com::Verify-Peer "false"
   Acquire::https::download.vscodium.com::Verify-Host "false"
   ```
3. Save this file, and run `sudo apt update` again as normal.

This *should* override the HTTPS validation for `download.vscodium.com` and permit you to interact with the repository.